# Comunicação de banco de dados SQL em Rede

Tags: sql-server, redes, sql-server-express

Tenho uma aplicação funcionando perfeitamente com o BD em um notebook. Mas gostaria de poder acessar com minha aplicação esse banco de dados através de outro dispositivo.

Então pensei em fazer essa comunicação via rede. Mas acontece que não sei nada sobre redes e não estou conseguindo me orientar sozinho sobre esse tema e nem os cuidados que devo ter para que alguém não autorizado tenha acesso.

Por onde posso começar a pesquisar para resolver meu problema? Preciso criar uma rede local pelo windows, ou apenas pelo Configuration Manager consigo fazer essa comunicação?

Comment: Qual o banco de dados? SQLite? MySQL?

Comment: SQL Server Express

Comment: Alterei as tags para que quem tenha o conhecimento específico possa te ajudar mais facilmente

Comment: Qual versão do sql express?

Comment: Sql Server Express 2016 SP1 - versão 13.0.4206.0.

Copiei esses dados, caso possa ser relevante.
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - 14.0.17119.0
Ferramentas de Cliente do Microsoft Analysis Services - 14.0.608.142

Comment: estou fazendo um roadmap já coloco aqui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Habilite as conexões por IP

No SQL Configuration Manager configure a sua instância para receber conexões por IP

### Habilite conexoes remotas

No Sql Management Studio clique com o botão direito no servidor, propriedades, conexões, habilitar conexões remotas conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Habilite conexão por Usuário e senha

No Sql Management Studio clique com o botão direito no servidor, propriedades, Segurança, Mudar o modo de conexão para "Mixed mode", ou seja, usuário do Windows ou do SQL Server conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Crie um usuário

Crie um novo usuário para conectar ao servidor. Abra a pasta de bancos de dados do servidor, Clique com o botão direito na pasta Logons e Novo Logon, conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com essas configurações deve ser possível conectar remotamente por uma conexão por IP\InstanciaSQLServer

Caso ocorra erro de permissão pode ser necessário habilitar a porta 1433 (porta padrão do SQL no firewall e conceder permissão para esse banco de dados com esse novo usuário. Mas essas configurações são mais simples e vale a pena tentar a conexão com o que já foi feito acima.